# I can't change height the title of ExpansionTile on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I try to add an ExpansionTile to a card.

It works well but the height of the title is really over than what I expected.

Here is the screenshot of the widget inspector:

[image]

As you see, the height of the title is 56. I need to remove the top and the bottom spaces, each of them is h=18.5.

I've tried adding padding, adding sizedbox but none of them worked.

Here is my ExpansionTile Code. Do you have any idea about this?

```
ExpansionTile(
      title: Text('Detay'),
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
              15, 0, 15, 10),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment:
                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              const Icon(Icons.more_time),
              Text(DateFormat(
                      'dd.MM.yyyy  kk:mm')
                  .format(order.createdDateTime
                      .toLocal())),
              if (order.createdUser != null)
                const Icon(Icons.person),
              if (order.createdUser != null)
                Text(
                  order.createdUser!.fullName,
                )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ])
```